# MPAndroidChart setGranularity(1.0f) doesn't work

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I really thanks to this [library](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart).
I am trying to draw Horizontal Bar Chart.

But I faced a problem.
I want to draw the chart Axis every one point.
So I used "setGranularity(1.0f);"

But the Axis is shown every 2 points.
When I use "setGranularity(3.0f)" or higher, it works fine.
But 1.0 doesn't work.
I don't know why.
And I can find a clue.

When the size of "List" is smaller than 8, "setGranularity(1.0f)" works fine.[image]

When the size of "List" is bigger than 9, "setGranularity(1.0f)" doesn't work.
(It works like "setGranularity(2.0f)".)[image]

I have the List size of 13.

How can I apply "setGranularity(1.0f)"?

Answer (score 7):

I found the solution.

When I called below method, "setGranularity(1.0f)" works fine.

```
barChart.getXAxis().setLabelCount(12);
```

Comment: Well done for finding your own solution! You may also need `barChart.getXAxs().setGranularityEnabled(true)`